# Any way to 'throttle' Python/Mongo function

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have an function that operates on a single collection, recursively doing two aggregations then updating documents.  All my indexes are correct.

At the moment I cannot refactor this code, and when the function runs it slams Mongo for about 10 minutes to process the data.  Seems to grow based on collection size, averaging about 60 seconds for every additional 3k documents.  This collection can grow to hundreds of thousands of documents.  (The documents are small - about 10 keys with very small values each.)

There is no need for the result of this function to be real-time - it is scheduled, so it's perfectly fine for me to throttle it back.

The question is, is there any way to tell *mongo* to limit the CPU it grants to an operation?  Or should I address the throttling in Python using `sleep` or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

> recursively doing two aggregations then updating documents

It looks like you need to consider to re-model your schema. The flexibility of MongoDB documents schema is something to optimise your process. See [MongoDB: Data Modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) for more infos, examples and patterns.

> The question is, is there any way to tell mongo to limit the CPU it grants to an operation?

MongoDB does not have a feature to limit a CPU usage per operation. This feature may not make sense in distributed fashion. For example, a limit of 1 CPU for an operation that spans multiple shards may not be as simple/desired anymore.

Alternatively, depending on your use case, if the function does not have to be real-time, you could utilise secondary [read-preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/). 
Essentially, directing your scheduled reporting to a secondary member, allowing your primary to process other data.

Although make sure you read the [pros](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#indications) and [cons](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#counter-indications) of this secondary read beforehand.

See also [MongoDB Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication)